# converting print statement output in loop into dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, string-matching

I am trying to adapt the following code from print statement to dataframe output.

```
places = ['England UK','Paris FRANCE','ITALY,gh ROME','New']  
location=['UK','FRANCE','ITALY']

def on_occurence(pos,location):
   print (i,':',location)
   
root = aho_create_statemachine(location)

for i in places:
  aho_find_all(i, root, on_occurence)
```

the print output for the above code is

England UK : UK

Paris FRANCE : FRANCE

ITALY,gh ROME : ITALY

I would like it so the df looked like:

| message | country |
| --- | --- |
| England UK | UK |
| Paris FRANCE | FRANCE |
| ITALY,gh ROME | ITALY |

I have tried the following with no luck

```
places = ['England UK','Paris FRANCE','ITALY,gh ROME','New']  
location=['UK','FRANCE','ITALY']

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["message","location"])
def on_occurence(pos,location):
   print (i,':',location)
df = df.append({"message":i,"location":location},ignore_index=True)

root = aho_create_statemachine(location)

for i in places:
  aho_find_all(i, root, on_occurence)
```

However the df looks like the following

| message | country |
| --- | --- |
| NEW | UK FRANCE ITALY |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(places, location)), columns = ["Message", "Country"])
 print(df)
```

My output:

```
         Message Country
0     England UK      UK
1   Paris FRANCE  FRANCE
2  ITALY,gh ROME   ITALY
```

If you want to print it without Row Index:

```
print(df.to_string(index=False))
```

Output in this case is:

```
   Message Country
England UK      UK
Paris FRANCE  FRANCE
ITALY,gh ROME   ITALY
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recomend using dictionarys instead of 2 separate lists EG:

```
placeAndLocation = {
    "england UK" : "UK",
    "Paris France" : "france"
}
```

and so on.

Then to loop through this use:

```
for place, location in placeAndLocation.items():
    print("place: " + place)
    print("location: " + location)
```

I find this easier as you can easily see what data field lines up with what value and the data is contained within one variavle makeing it easier to resd down the line